# Error building Hadoop 2.6 on Windows 8

Tags: maven, hadoop, build, windows-8.1

I'm following the tutorial to build and install hadoop. 
http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os

However, when I give the below command from the VS2010 command prompt:

```
 mvn package -Pdist,native-win -DskipTests -Dtar
```

I get the below error:

```
main:
[mkdir] Skipping C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native because it already exists.
 [exec] Current OS is Windows 8.1
 [exec] Executing 'cmake' with arguments:
 [exec] 'C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs/src/'
 [exec] '-DGENERATED_JAVAH=C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native/javah'
 [exec] '-DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=64'
 [exec] '-DREQUIRE_LIBWEBHDFS=false'
 [exec] '-DREQUIRE_FUSE=false'
 [exec] '-G'
 [exec] 'Visual Studio 10 Win64'
 [exec]
 [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
 [exec] not part of the command.
 Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'cmake' with arguments:
'C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs/src/'
'-DGENERATED_JAVAH=C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoophdfs\target/native/javah'
'-DJVM_ARCH_DATA_MODEL=64'
'-DREQUIRE_LIBWEBHDFS=false'
'-DREQUIRE_FUSE=false'
'-G'
'Visual Studio 10 Win64'

The ' characters around the executable and arguments are not part of the command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  1.781s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  1.333s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  1.030s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.375s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  2.104s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  6.628s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  1.047s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  1.173s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  1.594s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... SUCCESS [ 59.046s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SUCCESS [  1.905s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SUCCESS [  6.491s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SUCCESS [  0.150s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. FAILURE [ 19.351s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-api .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-common ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-server-tests ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-client ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-site ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-registry ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-yarn-project ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-app ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-mapreduce ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Ant Tasks ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:47 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-28T21:18:11+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 78M/363M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "native-bin" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified [ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 5:107 in C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run (make) on project hadoop-hdfs: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifiedaround Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 5:107 in C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifiedaround Ant part ...<exec failonerror="true" dir="C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target/native" executable="cmake">... @ 5:107 in C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
 Caused by: C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\antrun\build-main.xml:5: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:675)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:327)
    ... 22 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmake" (in directory "C:\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-project\hadoop-hdfs\target\native"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
    ... 34 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 40 more
```

I don't understand the error at all. I have cmake installed and C:\cmake\bin added to the path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...this error makes me think you had a typo in your Maven command:

`[WARNING] The requested profile "native-bin" could not be activated because it does not exist.`

Check your command; make sure it's `native-win`, not `native-bin`

I also [wrote a guide recently](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BweVwq32koypYm1QWHNvRTZWTm8/view) for building Hadoop on Server 2012 R2 (should be identical for 8.1). Let me know.